# React MUI: TextArea inside dialog focus issues

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get a multiline `TextField` working (correctly) inside a dialog component.

I have been struggling with this specific issue for a while now, I'm not sure if the issue is MUI related, or potentially todo with how my page (dialog) is re-rendering in react.

Please see the <strike>non-</strike>working example linked. [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-zkmhz)

I have tested numerous other approached too, eg restructuring my code, wrapping things in memo etc.. but to no avail...

**Currently 1 of 3 things happen.**

1.) No autofocus => impossible to type

[image: No autofocus]

2.) With autofocus => kind of solves the issue... the when losing focus, the input flashes

[image: with autofocus]

3.) With autofocus + multiline... the input loses focus as well (regains it, but the cursor is as the beginning of the input)

[image: autofocus and multiline]

**Theory**

I think this MIGHT be a bug in React MUI, & have have created a [bug ticket](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20466) for it, but I'd like to rule out that it might not be something else, eg the way I have composed the dialogs code, e.g, not memoizing the right things, state causing updates it shouldn't etc...

Comment: Have you tried to make the two states separate? I guess the reason is related to re-rendering when the conditional rendering state is been reset every time there is an input.

Comment: Just to clarify you're suggesting `[comment, setComment] = useState('')` vs `useState({ something: '', comment: '' })`... I'm sure I have... but I will double check again.

Comment: @keikai. here is a fork with split states... and the same seems to happen. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-dy5km

Comment: I had a similar issue, but it was because the ConfirmDialog (containing a TextField) was placed in an Autocomplete, it pop up when click on a Chip but focus was forced into the Autocomplete. I solved it extracting the ConfirmDialog into a separated component, using redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to do with the extracted `Content` internal component... and adding autofocus masked the problem by adding focus back the the newly created element on each key press.

I did a small test where I removed all the internal code blocks, and only kept the basic jsx, and the issue was gone. (also no more re-renders, thus confirming my suspicion)

I then added it back then memoized the Content section only.

Once I memoized it, it solved all the re-rendering issues. I don't know how I missed that initially, but Im' writing it off to getting lost in hunting down the issue :/

```
  const Content = useMemo(
    () =>  <Grid>... previous jsx</Grid>,
    [
      ReasonChips,
      feedback.comment,
      feedback.reason,
      isEditing,
      onSubmitClick,
      ratingOptions.length,
    ]
  );
```